# django filter and distinct

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

this is my data in admin site looks like

[image]

I use distinct() to  eliminates duplicate rows of Students Enrollment Record from the query results but I wonder why the result is like this

[image]

even though my html code is

```
{% for n in total %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{n.Teacher}}</td>
              <td>{{n.Subjects}}</td>
              <td>{{total.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
              <td>{{total}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

I have this distinct() code in my views.py

```
mystudent = grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records', flat=False).distinct()
```

and this is my model.py

```
class grade(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    Grading_Categories = models.ForeignKey(gradingCategories, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                           null=True, blank=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

can you guys please explain why the result is like this?

this is my current complete query

```
 id_list = grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records__id', flat=True).distinct()
 grades = grade.objects.filter(Students_Enrollment_Records_id__in=id_list)
 print(grades)
 rating = grade.objects.values('Grading_Categories').annotate(Average=Avg('Average'))
 print(id_list)
```

this is the current result

[image]

Comment: you have to add an order_by call also

Comment: okay mr @bmons ill try that

Comment: mystudent = grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records', flat=False).order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct() like this? but the result is the same

Comment: grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records__', flat=True).order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records__')., try with the specifice field name of FK and If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter

Comment: add the field name after double under score

Comment: mystudent=grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records__id', flat=True).order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records__id').distinct() I try this according to your comment but the result is still the same

Comment: instead of id try with a field name, without distinct

Comment: Please stop posting [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769800/how-to-use-filtering-data-while-using-distinct-method-in-django) multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get unique records, you should query for their Id's

```
id_list = grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records_id', flat=True).distinct()
grades = grade.objects.filter(Students_Enrollment_Records_id__in=id_list)
```

Comment: I try your answer sir but no record found

Comment: Can you show your complete query

Comment: I will post it.

Comment: please see my update sir

Comment: Your filter is wrong in 2nd line.. it should be Students_Enrollment_Records_id__in=id_list. Not id__in

Comment: yes, I change it now but the result is still the same

Comment: please see my update question sir

Comment: in this line grades = grade.objects.filter(Students_Enrollment_Records_id__in=id_list) I have error

Comment: Can you show that error

Answer (score 0):

You results are correct and this is expected behaviour, to fix this you have to parse data by youself using template_tag.

Explanation line by line:

```py
# first you get not list it's QuerySet, SQL statement is not executed in db
id_list = grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records__id', flat=True).distinct()

# than you filter by it, SQL statement is not executed in db
grades = grade.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)

# SQL executes in db, and you get results from QuerySet, which is list of grades objects
print(grades)

# Same thing, just QuerySet with annotation
rating = grade.objects.values('Grading_Categories').annotate(Average=Avg('Average'))

# SQL executes in db, and you get results from QuerySet which is just list of ids
print(id_list)
```

Example:

```
id_list = grade.objects.filter(Teacher = m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records__id', flat=True).distinct()

students = StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)

formated_students = [
    f'{student.name}' # I assume that student has name
    for student in students
]

students_to_output = ','.join(formated_students)

formated_grades = [
   f'Grading_Categories: {grade.Grading_Categories}, Average: {grade.Average}'
   for grade in grades
]
grades_to_output = ','.join(formated_grades)
```

Comment: just iterate through queryset and format it to string, if you need this in template you have to use [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).

Comment: can you make me an example using the existing code?

Comment: please see my update question @alex2007v

Comment: @MaryRoseVillaganasOrcullo see updated answer

Comment: how to print it in html ?

Comment: use [simple-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

Comment: return render(request, 'Homepage/index.html', {"students_to_output":students_to_output}) ? like this?

Comment: no, you have to this for each line in your table, don't touch your render, create simple tag and use it, in django documention you can find example how to work with it