# How to use filtering data while using distinct method in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

please help me on my problem I hope my title is enough to understand what I mean, please help me on this problem guys.

When I tried this:

```
id_list = grade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records_id',flat=True).distinct()
```

[image]
I use `distinct()` to eliminates duplicate rows of Students Enrollment Record from the query results but I wonder why the result is like this:

[image]

What should I do to show the Students name not that QuerySet in my html?

This is my current **views.py**:

```
id_list = grade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records_id',flat=True).distinct()
print(id_list)
grades = grade.objects.filter(Students_Enrollment_Records_id__in=id_list)
print(grades)
```

This is my **models.py**:

```
class grade(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    Grading_Categories = models.ForeignKey(gradingCategories, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                           null=True, blank=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**UPDATE**

when I tried this

```
piste = grade.objects.filter(Teacher_id=m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records').annotate(Average=Avg('Average')).order_by('Grading_Categories').distinct()
```

the computation is fix but the teacher name, Subject and Name of students didn't display but the ID is display just like this

[image]

this is my desire answer

[image]

this is how I post in html

views.py

```
return render(request, 'Homepage/index.html', {"piste":piste})
```

html

```
{% for n in piste %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{n.Teacher}}</td>
              <td>{{n.Subjects}}</td>
              <td>{{n.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
              <td>{{n}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

This is model.py

```
class EmployeeUser(models.Model):
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    Employee_Number = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    My_Department = models.ForeignKey(Department, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    My_Position = models.ForeignKey(Position, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Educational_Attainment = models.ForeignKey(EducationalAttainment, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                               null=True)
    Landline = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mobile_Number = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Facebook_Acoount = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    Fathers_Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Fathers_Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Fathers_Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500, )
    Educational_Attainment_Father = models.ForeignKey(EducationalAttainment, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                      null=True)
    Father_Occupation = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Father_Company_Employed = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Father_Landline = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Father_MobileNo = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Father_Email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Father_Facebook_Account = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    Mother_FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mother_Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mother_Maiden_LastName = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Educational_AttainmentID_Mother = models.ForeignKey(EducationalAttainment, related_name='+',
                                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Mother_Occupation = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mother_Company_Employed = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mother_Landline = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mother_MobileNo = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mother_Email = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Mother_Facebook_Account = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Family_Status = models.ForeignKey(FamilyStatu, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Country = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    ZIP_Postal_Code = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    State_Province = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    City = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Barangay = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Unit_Number_Street = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    LandMark = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    AddressLine1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    AddressLine2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    AddressLine3 = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Firstname}   {0.Middle_Initial}      {0.Lastname}'
        return suser.format(self)

class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True)
```

this is the full view.py

```
m = EmployeeUser.objects.get(Username=request.POST['p_user'], Password = request.POST['p_pass'], My_Position =request.POST['position'])
piste = grade.objects.all().filter(Teacher=m.id).values_list('Students_Enrollment_Records').annotate(Average=Avg('Average')).order_by('Grading_Categories').distinct()
return render(request, 'Homepage/index.html', {"piste":piste})
```

UPDATE

when i tried this answer of mr @nigel222

```
piste = grade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).annotate(grade_average=Avg('Average')).order_by('Grading_Categories').distinct()
```

and to my html

```
{% for n in piste %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{n.Teacher}}</td> <!-- 1 -->
          <td>{{n.Subjects}}</td> <!-- 2 -->
          <td>{{n.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}
               </td>  <!-- 3 -->
          <td>{{n}}</td>  <!--4 -->
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

i get this result

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but it appears you posted your whole EmployeeUser model and it lacks a method to set and check a password using a hashing mechanism. Does that live elsewhere or are you storing the passwords in plaintext?

Comment: I am  storing the passwords in plaintext mr @schillingt

Comment: Please, please, please do not do that. Instead extend Django's built-in user and/or the BaseAbstractUser: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: okay ill do that mr @schillingt next time, kind you please help me on my problem? almost 3-4 days I cant figure out on how to fix this problem

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to render.

Comment: I want to distinct the Students_Enrollment_Records and compute their final rating per student

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206076/discussion-between-mary-rose-villaganas-orcullo-and-schillingt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with Django much for a couple of years, but this is what I think is happening.

You're assigning a values_list (a tuple) to `piste`. You're not assigning `grade` objects to `piste`.  However, in your template you're expecting the elements of `piste` to be grades.

I believe you need to get the `grade` object first and send that to the template as well as the `piste`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `values_list` (which is the data you are getting in column 4). You want a queryset of `grade` objects:

```
piste = grade.objects.filter(Teacher_id=m.id
        ).annotate(Average=Avg('Average')
        ).order_by('Grading_Categories'
        ).distinct()
```

and then in your template, something like

```
{% for n in piste %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{n.Teacher}}</td> <!-- 1 -->
          <td>{{n.Subjects}}</td> <!-- 2 -->
          <td>{{n.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}
               </td>  <!-- 3 -->
          <td>{{n}}</td>  <!--4 -->
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

1 and 2 render `EmployeeUser` and `Subject` objects. 1 will return  the `__str__` representation of `EmployeeUser` which ought to be OK. Alternatively you can explicitly use `{{n.Teacher.FirstName}}` etc. in your template.

3 I don't understand, because you don't show the `Students_Enrolled_Subject` model.

4 is now wrong.  Perhaps you want the annotation `{{n.Average}}`?

Please, as soon as possible, learn to use Django/ Python coding conventions. `Model` subclasses (and Python class names in general) start with a capital letter. Instances of classes are lowercase. Fieldnames/attributes are normally lower_case and definitely start with a lowercase letter. Model subclass names are a singular name not a plural name. Not doing this is horribly confusing to any experiemced Django coder. So,

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True)
    grading_categories = models.ForeignKey(GradingCategory, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       null=True, blank=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    students_enrollment_records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: I will try this sir , please wait

Comment: When I copy your answer sir, I encounter this error """The annotation 'Average' conflicts with a field on the model."""

Comment: It does. Annotations are things you dynamically add to the model. Change the name of either the field or the annotation.

Comment: Sir i add the StudentsEnrolledSubject, please see it

Comment: what should i change in your answer to correct this error ""The annotation 'Average' conflicts with a field on the model.""

Comment: Change the name of the annotation to (say) `grade_average`, assuming that `Average` really is a field of a `grade` object i.e. a column of its database table.

Comment: sir when i tried your answer i get this result, i will post it

Comment: 3. is wrong. `{{n.Students_Enrollment_Records}}` is a `StudentsEnrolledSubject` instance, so the next name in the chain must be a field thereof, either `Students_Enrollment_Records` or `Subject_Section_Teacher`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206075/discussion-between-mary-rose-villaganas-orcullo-and-nigel222).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do for you. I think you should be selected based on the student and filtering the grades to the teacher. I also did a prefetch for all of the subjects since I can't quite tell what you need done there.

```
students = Student.objects.filter(
    grades__teacher_id=teacher.id,
).annotate(
    total_avg=Avg('grades__Average')
).prefetch_related('grades__Subjects')
```

Template:

```
{% for student in students %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{teacher}}</td>
          <td>{{student.grades.subjects.all}}</td>
          <td>{{student}}</td>
          <td>{{student.total_avg}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id' i encounter this error