# How to use distinct() method without applying values() method using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is my current code in views.py

```
students = grade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).annotate(total_avg=Avg('Average')).prefetch_related('Subjects').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct()
```

this is the result:

[image]

As you can see the 2 ROSE L TRiNIDAD exist, and it didn't compute the final ratings, but when I use the `values()`

```
students=grade.objects.values('Students_Enrollment_Records').filter(Teacher=m.id).annotate(total_avg=Avg('Average')).prefetch_related('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct()
```

the result is

[image]

The distinct() method is applied and it computes the final ratings, but as you can see the name of the teacher, subject and the students didn't display.

This is my html:

```
{% for student in students %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{student.Teacher}}</td>
          <td>{{student.Subjects}}</td>
          <td>{{student.Students_Enrollment_Records}}</td>
          <td>{{student.total_avg}}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

My models.py:

```
class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True)


class grade(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    Grading_Categories = models.ForeignKey(gradingCategories, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                           null=True, blank=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class EmployeeUser(models.Model):
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    Employee_Number = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
   .
   .
```

**Note: this is a different question with the same result**, [How to use filtering data while using distinct method in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769800/how-to-use-filtering-data-while-using-distinct-method-in-django/59773329#59773329)

Can you please explain to me why when I use values() the name of the student display ID(56 and 57) only not the name, as shown in the image?

[image]

UPDATE when I use

```
students=grade.objects.values('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records').filter(Teacher=m.id).annotate(total_avg=Avg('Average')).prefetch_related('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct()

class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Discount_Type = models.ForeignKey(Discount, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                                         null=True)
    Remarks = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

[image]

the name of the teacher and student, subject are not displaying.

when i tried this

```
students=grade.objects.values('Teacher', 'Subjects', 'Students_Enrollment_Records').filter(Teacher=m.id).annotate(total_avg=Avg('Average')).prefetch_related('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct()
```

this is the result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can you guys please explain to me why when i use values() the name of the student display ID(56 and 57) only not the name??

As [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) says

> The values() method takes optional positional arguments, *fields, which specify field names to which the SELECT should be limited

So when you call `values('Students_Enrollment_Records')` you got only this foreign key id in result

Add more fields in `values()` and you will get them in result too

For exsample if you need name of `Students_Enrollment_Records` model object and it is stored in model field `name` you should add `'Students_Enrollment_Records__name'` to values()

#### In the end this solution was used for this case:

query

```
students = grade.objects.filter(Teacher=m.id).values('Teacher__Username', 'Subjects__Description', 'Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Username').annotate(total_avg=Avg('Average')).order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct()
```

html

```
{% for student in students %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{student.Teacher__Username}}</td>
        <td>{{student.Subjects__Description}}</td>
        <td>{{student.Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Username}}</td>
        <td>{{student.total_avg}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: when i tried this mr @weAreDust """students=grade.objects.values('Students_Enrollment_Records__name')""" , i encounter this error """Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: Students_Enrollment_Records, Students_Enrollment_Records_id, Subject_Section_Teacher, Subject_Section_Teacher_id, id"""

Comment: Let me see your `Students_Enrollment_Records` class code (add it to your question)

Comment: @MaryRoseVillaganasOrcullo I mean StudentsEnrollmentRecord class (add it to your question)

Comment: I will post the result of your answer sir

Comment: Did you change html as I suggested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206265/discussion-between-wearestardust-and-mary-rose-villaganas-orcullo).

Comment: @MaryRoseVillaganasOrcullo don't forget to add `.order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records')`, watch my last update